# Count the number of lines in a file - C

Tags: c, count, lines, readfile

I'm receiving an input file, with a bunch of lines.
I want to be able to count the lines but also analyse them.

the input will be many lines of code with only integers. 
ex:

```
3 2
1 2
2 3
4 3
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

here's the tricky part:
the first line has two numbers: the 3 and the 2. (the 3 isn't relevant for now).
The 2 is really important. It represents the number of lines I have to read and save.
So, according to this example I would have to save the lines

```
1 2
2 3
```

So why are there other lines? - you ask. Well, let's see this input as blocks.
After the line `3 2` I read the two lines. So it's like that block ended.
But then, line `4 3` came along. This means I have to do the exact same thing I did with the first block. So, from line `4 3` I now know I have to read and save the next 3 lines. meaning the lines

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

I've been head over hills for this and can't seem to find any possible solution

Comment: What did you try? Did you read a good C programming book? Did you look into the source code of similar free software?

Comment: Try writing some pseudocode first, ignoring all the syntax. This is an exercise in structuring a fairly simple algorithm.

Comment: If you have control over the format, I'd suggest you go for a more human-friendly format, i.e., start a block with `block 4` and end it with `end` or so. The difference in runtime will be negligible (unless it is reams and reams of this stuff), mistakes in generating/processing are much easier to diagnose, and even your not-so-bright-and-careless intern will be able to create files in that format, with skipped lines not getting everything following utterly out of sync.

Comment: paste what you have tried as Basile said

Answer (score 1):

When you've got a problem like this, it's useful to think of the structure first. Here's one method in simple pseudocode for the main algorithm to get you started. People can't really help unless you present your code and a problem with it.

```
declare line buffer array

while (read a line into buffer == succeeds) {
   scan buffer for two numbers (m, n)
   loop how many times? {
      read a line into buffer
      scan buffer for next two numbers (x, y)
   }
}
```

That shouldn't be too difficult to translate into C. You can then expand it to store the numbers you've scanned, count the lines, or whatever else.

Once you've got some code, if it doesn't work and you can't figure out what's going wrong, you'll get plenty of help.